# Why am I not getting the minimum from the following program(using functions and arrays)

Tags: c, arrays, function

I was trying to find the maximum and minimum value using arrays and function. I was able to get the maximum value, however, minimum doesn't seen to be popping up. its giving some random number which i believe is an inode number. How do i get the minimum value from the following program?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    void get(int array[], int size);
    void print(int array[], int size);
    int max(int array[], int size);
    int min(int array[], int size);
    int main ()
    {
        int max_value, min_value;
        int list[10];
        get(list, 10);
        print(list,10); 
        max_value = max(list, 10);
        min_value = min(list,10);
        printf("The maximum number in the arrays is %d\n", max_value);
        printf("The minimum number in the array is %d\n", min_value);
    }
    void get(int array[], int size)
    {
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<10; i++)
            array[i] = rand();
    }
    void print(int array[], int size)
    {
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<10; i++)
            printf("%d\n", array[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    int max(int array[], int size)
    {
        int i,max;
        max=array[0];
        for(i=0; i<10; i++)
            array[i];
        if (array[i]>max)
            max = array[i];
        return max;
    }

    int min(int array[], int size)
    {
        int i, min;
        min = array[0];
        for (i=0; i<10; i++)
            array[i];
        if(array[i]<min)
            min = array[i];
        return min;
    }
```

Comment: Oh, fixing indentation made the problem obvious. Should I say sorry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. In your

```
int min(int array[], int size)
{
int i, min;
min = array[0];
{         /* put brace here */
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
 array[i];
if(array[i]<min)
 min = array[i];
}        /* and close it here */
return min;
}
```

you set min to be first element of array. 
Then you loop over array doing nothing. And then check if array[10] < min.
That won't return mininum value.
Follow my comments to make it work.
Remember that body of the loop consists of block of code. That means that without `{ }` it looks at one instruction as everything it has to do in one iteration.

There might also be no instruction at all. Just put `;` after the loop condition and you get yourself a loop with no instructions in it.

Also, you assume that your array will be 10-items long. What if not? Why don't you use variable `size` you pass to function to check for end of you array?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your **for** statements. You need the scopes brackets.
e.g.

```
// What is actually done
for( /* params */ )
    // First line is ran
// Line here is not executed by the for-loop
```

What you need to do is :

```
// Good for-loop statement
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ // SCOPE begin
    /*
        Code executed
    */
 } // loop ended
```

Since you defined **i** outside of the for-loop, it doesn't show you any error. However, it won't work properly.